# Active button error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, helper

how are you? I'm having a problem with a program I'm modifying.
is a series site I almost managed to solve everything else I arrived at a point that is difficult to identify the problem.

In the page of the series to be displayed the seasons appear and also the episodes appear.

The buttons of the first episode of each season appear highlighted as if they were being watched, and when I click on an episode everyone is unmarked and what I clicked becomes active.
I want the only thing to stay active is episode 1 of the first season which is what is being displayed on screen and the other first episodes are turned off.

the problem is in the following line:

```
<?php 
    if($episode['stream_key']==$current_key){ 
        echo 'btn-success';
    } else {
        if($current_key=='000000' && $i=='1'){ 
            echo 'btn-success';
        }else{ 
            echo 'btn-default';
        }
    }
?>
```

the line below is to understand the context:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12  m-t-10 m-b-10">

        <?php
            $this->db->order_by('seasons_id', "ASC");
            $seasons = $this->db->get_where('seasons',array('videos_id'=>$watch_videos->videos_id))->result_array();
            foreach ($seasons as $season):                                       

         ?>
         <?php if($this->common_model->get_num_episodes_by_seasons_id($season['seasons_id']) > 0): ?>

        <div class="season">                                        

            <p class="btn btn-inline text-uppercase" style="font-size: 12px;color: #055b86">TEMP: <?php echo $season['seasons_name']; ?> | EP: </p>

                <?php

                    $this->db->group_by('seasons_id');
                    $this->db->order_by('seasons_id', "ASC");
                    $this->db->group_by('episodes_id');
                    $this->db->order_by('episodes_id', "ASC");
                    $episodes = $this->db->get_where('episodes',array('videos_id'=>$watch_videos->videos_id,'seasons_id'=> $season['seasons_id']))->result_array();

                    $i=0;

                    $current_key = '000000';

                    if(isset($_GET['key']))
                        $current_key = $_GET['key'];
                        foreach($episodes as $episode):
                            $i++;

                 ?>

                <a href="<?php echo base_url().'watch/'.$watch_videos->slug.'.html?key='.$episode['stream_key']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-inline <?php if($episode['stream_key']==$current_key){ echo 'btn-success';}else {} ?>" style="font-size: 10px; margin-bottom:5px !important;"><?php echo $episode['episodes_name']; ?></a>

                <?php endforeach; ?>                                        

            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    </div>
```